# Entering values into an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to "dump" all the values in 2 columns into 2 separate arrays. Currently these columns contain 12k+ values in each (each column has the same amount of data).

I came across a suggestion that I could use the Range function to do the dump (as below):

```
With ActiveSheet
    eLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

aRow = 2

cBIN = Range(Cells(2, 26), Cells(eLastRow, 26))
dDealer = Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(eLastRow, 4))

While aRow <= eLastRow

    Cells(aRow, 35) = cBIN(aRow - 2) & " - " & dDealer(aRow - 2)

    aRow = aRow + 1

Wend
```

However, when I try to use the code in the While function, nothing is generated.

Edit: Any suggestions how I can get the values into an array without having to had each one individually to each array?

Comment: you should be getting an error.  do you have a `On Error Resume Next` in your code that is masking the error?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `While aRow <= eLastRow`?. Arrays from ranges are always 2D and 1-based so you would get an error anyway.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I am using the error catcher. When I take it off, I get run time error 12 - type mismatch

Comment: @SJR - you are correct. Edited it to reflect correct use

Comment: on which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dump a range into an array make sure that your `cBIN`, and `dDealer` variables are of type `variant`  you then need to use the `Resize` function.
like this:

```
cBIN = Cells(2, 26).Resize(eLastRow, 26)
dDealer = Cells(2, 4).Resize(eLastRow, 4)
```

Then you have two arrays populated with the data from each range.  What this does is take the first range then resizes it to the row and col specified (the last row) and column, then dumps that info into your variant array.

Comment: What type of data are you trying to dump into the array.  I just tried this and it worked without a hitch.  You changed your variable to type `Variant` and it still gave you an issue?

Comment: make sure on your `Variant` variable you do not add `()` to the end just type it as `cBIN as variant` not `cBIN() as variant`

Answer (score 2):

use a for loop.

Also since you are already using With, include all the references to that sheet.

And arrays set by direct assignment from ranges are 1 based and 2 dimensional.

Also when assigning a range to an array the array must be declared as a variant

```
Dim cBIN as Variant, dDealer as Variant
Dim eLastRow as Long, arow as Long
With ActiveSheet
    eLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    
    cBIN = .Range(.Cells(2, 26), .Cells(eLastRow, 26))
    dDealer = .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(eLastRow, 4))

    For arow = 2 To eLastRow 
        .Cells(arow, 35) = cBIN(arow - 1, 1) & " - " & dDealer(arow - 1, 1)
    Next arow
End With
```

Comment: I realise I can take this approach, however, I am looking at the method of putting the values into the array in bulk. I've edited the question to more accurately reflect the issue

Comment: @Clauric it is putting the values into the array in bulk.  I don't understand, the only thing I changed was using a for loop which is quicker than a while loop when dealing with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply use a formula since the source data located on the sheet, then replace formulas with values, that is much faster than processing within loop:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range(.Cells(2, 35), .Cells(i, 35))
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]&"" - ""&RC[-31]"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```